# wait with console code until timer on page gets to 10 seconds left

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript code that activates a process on a html page, that starts counting down form 20 seconds to zero. when the countdown reaches 10 seconds, I want it to do something else.

**Failed option 1: while(countdown > 10)**

this get the page stuck, since JS is single threaded.

**Failed option 2: setTimeout(things I want to do, time to wait)**

the whole thing is inside a for loop. if I use this, the function I pass to the timeout will be executed in the right time, but the code will immediately go to the next for loop iteration - I want it to wait until the function passed to setTimeout to be completed before moving on.

how can I achieve this?

PSUDO CODE:

```
for i=0 to i=10:
    start countdown on the page from 20 to 0 
    while (countdown > 10)
        wait while page countdown is ongoing
    only after countdown = 0
        do somthing
    only after doing the thing, start another iteration of the for loop
```

*whole of this should run in*

Comment: hey share your code

Comment: Once countdown reaches 10 seconds call a promise to do something else and when it's done continue counting down to zero.

Comment: Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this:

```js
let countdown = 0;

function startCountdown(count) {
  countdown = count;
  let timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  function tick() {
    countdown--;
    console.log(countdown);

    if(countdown <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }
  console.log(countdown);
}

function countdownUntil(count) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    function check() {
      if(countdown <= count) {
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(check);
    }
    check();
  })
}


async function start() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('start loop ' + i);
    
    startCountdown(20);
    
    await countdownUntil(10);

    console.log('10 seconds');

    await countdownUntil(0);

    console.log('end loop ' + i);
  }
}

start();
```

Comment: only an if statement is needed here `if(countdown === 10) await doSomething();`

Comment: @matrixersp I think it's better to do something when the countdown depletes, at least unregister the timer.

Comment: this is not helpful, since any code afterwards will run before the countdown finish, in-between the seconds.

Comment: @מורןרזניק Oh, so the `countdown` is not created by you, I've updated the code. If you can access the `countdown`, just use the code that after the comments.

Comment: Can you please explain how your code fixes the problem? currently, it is not clear to me

Comment: @מורןרזניק Basically the `check` function runs every frame (60 times per second by default). Every iteration it checks whether the `counter` is below a certain value(`10` at the beginning). If it's true, print `do something` and lower the value by one. So it will be called every second after the `countdown` is below 10.

Comment: if I add console.log('end') after the last line of your code, it still prints it before the first 'do somthing', which misses the point

Comment: @מורןרזניק You don't put the code anywhere you want. I've updated the answer, only put the code inside of the `doSomething` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222705/discussion-between---and-hao-wu).